# mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (19x1 and 19x1)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a handmade dataset and all want to do is set a linear regression model with Pytorch.
These are the codes I wrote:

```
from torch.autograd import Variable

train_x = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,4,6,8,5,2,1,1,6])
train_y = train_x * 2

X = Variable(torch.from_numpy(train_x).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad = False).view(19, 1)
y = Variable(torch.from_numpy(train_y).type(torch.FloatTensor), requires_grad = False)
from torch import nn


lr = nn.Linear(19, 1) 

loss = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(lr.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
output = lr(X) #error occurs here
```

I guess this is the simplest Pytorch neural network code in the world but it's still giving this error message:

```
mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (19x1 and 19x1)
```

I just did all the things on the book but it's still giving this error. Can you help me?

Comment: To take the inner product of two vectors using matrix multiplication, you have to transpose the second vector. To put it another way, the shapes of your matrices are incompatible for multiplication -- you have 19x1 and 19x1, but you need the number of columns of mat1 to equal the number of rows of mat2 (19x1 and 1x19)

Comment: @Andy, I guess the second matrix is the matrix of weights, right? So, if I edit my code like "lr = nn.Linear(1, 19)", I'll be fix it. Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a [`torch.nn.Linear(a,b)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) as part of a network, then the input must be of shape `(n, a)`, and the output will be of shape `(n, b)`. Therefore you need to make sure that `X` has shape `(n, 19)` in your case, so modifying it with

```
...).view(1, 19)
```

would do the trick.